# How can i encode json first column as object by id

Tags: php, json

How can i `json_encode` the first column named id, with values to json object, and after that encode the rest of the columns, with data as child json objects? my json is ***Valid***

```
{
    "id"        :"1",
    "first_name":"Henry",
    "last_name" :"Lawrence",
    "email"     :"hlawrence0@storify.com",
    "country"   :"Italy",
    "ip_address":"0.72.132.192"
}
```

I would like the output to be like:

```
  {
    "id"        :"1"{
    "first_name":"Henry",
    "last_name" :"Lawrence",
    "email"     :"hlawrence0@storify.com",
    "country"   :"Italy",
    "ip_address":"0.72.132.192"
}}
  {
    "id"        :"2"{
    "first_name":"Bonny",
    "last_name" :"Jackson",
    "email"     :"bjdsa0@storify.com",
    "country"   :"Italy",
    "ip_address":"0.72.132.192"
}}
```

Comment: The output you want is invalid JSON. Do you want something like, [{"firstname":""},{"firstname":""},{"firstname":""}]? Where the index of the value is equal to the id.

Comment: I just need the ids as objects and the data that belongs to it, to be encoded as child objects, so that i am able to select the id, and get the data that belongs to it. 

So what i would be looking for is, {"id":"2"},{"first_name":"Bonny" ... }}

Comment: The child objects would need an index. For example, {"id":1, "data":{"first_name":""}}, is this what you're looking for? Unless you don't care that there's `id`, then Laurent's answer will work fine.

Comment: So the child objects would need another object for data objects?

Comment: No, they would need a name. You will either have {"1":{"first_name":""}}, or [{"id":"1", "data":{"first_name":""}}, ...], not both, not a hybrid.

Comment: The second one, would be nice [{"id":"1", "data":{"first_name":""}}, ...],

Answer (score 0):

You can do as such:

```
$json = '{"id":"1","first_name":"Henry","last_name":"Lawrence","email":"hlawrence0@storify.com","country":"Italy","ip_address":"0.72.132.192"}';
$jsonEncode = json_decode($json, true);
$userArray[array_shift($jsonEncode)] = $jsonEncode;
$result = json_encode($userArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php

$json = '[{
    "id"        :"1",
    "first_name":"Henry",
    "last_name" :"Lawrence",
    "email"     :"hlawrence0@storify.com",
    "country"   :"Italy",
    "ip_address":"0.72.132.192"
},{
    "id"        :"2",
    "first_name":"Dave",
    "last_name" :"Chen",
    "email"     :"null@null",
    "country"   :"Canada",
    "ip_address":"127.0.0.1"
},{
    "id"        :"4",
    "first_name":"Foo",
    "last_name" :"Bar",
    "email"     :"postmaster@localhost",
    "country"   :"US",
    "ip_address":"0.0.0.0"
}]';

$json = json_decode($json, true);

array_walk($json, function(&$val) {
    $tmp = $val;
    $val = array('id' => $tmp['id']);
    unset($tmp['id']);
    $val['data'] = $tmp;
});

print_r($json);
```

[Output](https://eval.in/private/14f16f21db6e23):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [first_name] => Henry
                    [last_name] => Lawrence
                    [email] => hlawrence0@storify.com
                    [country] => Italy
                    [ip_address] => 0.72.132.192
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [first_name] => Dave
                    [last_name] => Chen
                    [email] => null@null
                    [country] => Canada
                    [ip_address] => 127.0.0.1
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [first_name] => Foo
                    [last_name] => Bar
                    [email] => postmaster@localhost
                    [country] => US
                    [ip_address] => 0.0.0.0
                )

        )

)
```